# What is the Japanese term for putting an arm around another's shoulder?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, words, terminology

What is the Japanese term for putting an arm around another's shoulder? it is kind of hard, at first I am thinking of 抱きしめる but I think it is more about embracing someone (tightly).

Thank you for the responds

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @l'électeur's answer, we also commonly say [肩【かた】を組【く】む](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E8%82%A9%E3%82%92%E7%B5%84%E3%82%80&tbm=isch) when two or more people put their arms on one another's shoulders.

Answer (score 3):

Most commonly, we would say:

> 「(Person)の肩{かた}に腕{うで}をかける」 or
>
> 「(Person)の肩に腕を回{まわ}す」

I actually could not think of another phrase.

Comment: Is it possible to use 「肩を 引き寄せる」?